# TinyMCE. Replacing/adding htmls tags with style from css?

Tags: tinymce-4

Is there a way to add new HTML tags and to make TinyMCE take its formatting from a CSS file?

I've been looking for ways of adding new formats but the internal TinyMCE formatting engine is not as flexible as CSS.

I'll clarify:

TinyMCE works by using standard html formatting tags:

```
<p>, <h1>, etc.
```

I'd like to either, create a new format that creates a new tag such as `<custom_1>`. That way I'd be able to format it with the css linked to the output document.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "add new HTML tags"? Add them where? Do you mean invent new ones?

Comment: Re your second question, `content_css` should do what you need? https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-appearance/

Comment: @Pekka웃 thanks! I kinda replied myself for the second part. If i find a way to make Tiny use custom html tags, i'll be able to format them with the document's html or even with content_css to format inside the editor.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "custom HTML tags"? Can you make an example?

Comment: Ah, I see now. If you don't get those rendered, that's not TinyMCE's fault - it's the *browser* that doesn't know what to do with them. What are you trying to do that you need this for?

Comment: I want to make TinyMCE use custom formats that are not defined by its internal formatting code but by using .CSS.

Comment: Last time I checked, TinyMCE didn't have an "internal formatting code" - it's basically a set of buttons and Javascript functions built around a div that is [`contentEditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable), like all other in-browser WYSIWYG editors on the market that I know of. The rendering of the elements is up to the browser. Can you make an example of what you would like to change?

Comment: Apparently there is an [API to create custom elements now,](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/) but it would likely be a nightmare (or at least a lot of wor) to integrate with TinyMCE. I don't think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: And what about being able to name divs: <div id=""> or <div class=">. The end result is being able to format the page 100% with css. I may just use the default html tags TinyCME uses, but i find that unelegant. Perhaps there is no other way.

Comment: Can you give an illustrated example of what you want?